# Where can I find the "Customize On/Off" option?

Tags: sonarqube

In our Sonar Build Environment we use SonarQube Server Version 5.6.6 (64-Bit) and our analysis runs on a Sonar Client Build Operating System with Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS (64-Bit).

Recently I have upgraded SonarQube from 5.1 to 5.6.6 (LTS). But under "Project Code" the "Customize ON|OFF" option is now missing.

Currently I can see only these options:

- Lines of Code
- Bugs
- Vulnerabilities
- Code Smells
- Coverage
- Duplications

In SonarQube version 5.1 I was using the "Customize ON|OFF" option to customize and add required columns.

How can I enable this feature back in SonarQube 5.6.6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature does not exist any longer (it has been dropped when rewriting the Project space), and there's currently no plan to reintroduce it.

Comment: Ok Thanks Fabrice for quick response.